# why some of my vs code's extension are disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-code

why these extensions are disabled by vscode? I tried enabling them but got no success. what to do?

**Got this problem, after updating the vscode**

[image]

Comment: if there VSCode engine requirement is bigger than your VSCode version, or the activation function generates an exception, Install the VSCode Insider and see if that enables the extension

Comment: I downgraded my vscode to the previous version, then also, facing the same issue.

Comment: try it with `VSCode Insiders`